# Having issues with line breaks in kivy button label

Tags: python, user-interface, csv, kivy, line-breaks

I am working on a little Kivy-based app for windows that displays a table of data in the form of a button grid.

Some of these buttons contain large chunks of text including line breaks. The list of button labels are contained in a csv file with in text \n intended to act as line breaks. Below is the code I use to make a button. When I use this, the \n does not actually trigger the new line, but rather just is included in my button label text.

```
with open(csvFILE.csv,'rb') as csvFile:
    csvData = csv.reader(csvFile)
        for row in csvData
            for col in row
                btnText=col
                btnHeight=60
                btnWidth=600
                colAlingment='left'
                btn = Button(text=('[color=000000]'+btnText+'[/color]'),markup=True , size_hint_y=None, height=btnHeight, size_hint_x=None, width=btnWidth, text_size=(btnWidth-10,None), halign = colAlingment, valign = 'middle')
                layout.add_widget(btn)
```

CSV File:

```
"Col1","Col2","Col3"
"Row 1 Col1",,Row 1 Col3
"Row 2 Col1","Row 2,some text\n Col2", ,
```

Perhaps the issue is coming from my use of " in the csv, but I need to use this to allow for strings that have commas in the (usually included in the same strings that have linebreaks in them as they can be 100s of char long).

Comment: It sounds like the \n is being escaped somehow.. try not using the () around the text, as in text="[color=000000]%s[/color]" % btnText, markup=True etc.. and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Totem I tried your suggestion, but I didn't work. That said, you made me realize that the issue is likely with how i bring my data in from the CSV. I have updated my question accordingly and would love a second opinion.